# HTML - How to select one id from a list of ids in querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing the following codes. There are repeating codes for the same function. I wonder if there is a way to include all the ids in one querySelector such that there are no repeats. Only the id in the selector is different.

The code is here:

```
function refreshMessage() {
  courseSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
    'message': 1
  }));
};

document.querySelector('#next-student').onclick = function(e) {
  refreshMessage();
};

document.querySelector('#put-back').onclick = function(e) {
  refreshMessage();
};

document.querySelector('#invite').onclick = function(e) {
  refreshMessage();
};

document.querySelector('#clear-queue').onclick = function(e) {
  refreshMessage();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all selectors...

```
const ids = ['next-student', 'put-back', 'invite', 'clear-queue'];
for (const id of ids) {
  document.getElementById(id).onclick = refreshMessage;
}
```

Or use event delegation

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('#next-student, #put-back, #invite, #clear-queue')) {
    refreshMessage();
  }
});
```

Comment: Event delegation would be even better if there is some common container holding the elements.  It is a very powerful tool and is underused.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#next-student, #put-back, #invite, #clear-queue,[name=rdoGroup]").forEach(function(element) {
  element.onclick = function(e) {
    refreshMessage();
  }
});

function refreshMessage(){
  console.log("REFRESHING!");
}
```

```html
<button id="next-student">Next</button>
<button id="put-back">Put Back</button>
<button id="invite">Invite</button>
<button id="clear-queue">Clear</button>
<label><input  type="radio" name="rdoGroup"> Yes</label>
<label><input  type="radio" name="rdoGroup"> No</label>
```

Or better yet, which preserves any existing on click listeners:

```js
let selectors = ["#next-student", "#put-back", "#invite", "#clear-queue", "[name=rdoGroup]"];

document.querySelectorAll(selectors.join(",")).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", refreshMessage);
});

function refreshMessage() {
  console.log("REFRESHING!");
}
```

```html
<button id="next-student">Next</button>
<button id="put-back">Put Back</button>
<button id="invite">Invite</button>
<button id="clear-queue">Clear</button>
<label><input  type="radio" name="rdoGroup"> Yes</label>
<label><input  type="radio" name="rdoGroup"> No</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The first one is what I was wondering if something like it exists.

Comment: @boyic, if you find it helpful don't forget to click the tick to accept and/or up vote